# Compiler Error CS0246 Listener Service IIS 2008 R2

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

I have inherited a project after my colleague moved on. I have a C# project for a listener service that will be called by a cloud based application sending us requests and data. All tests work fine in dev, the problem occurs when I deploy the application on IIS 2008 R2.

The Target Framework set in the project in Visual Studio is .Net Framework 4.5.

The Virtual Directory on IIS that contains the compiled application is within an application pool set to use '.Net Framework v4.0.30319'. From my research I've seen that this Framework version should work with all applications deployed for v4.5.

The virtual directory contains the asmx file for the listener service, the Web.Config file and a bin directory containing all the binaries.

When I call the asmx file in IE I get the following error:

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XXX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The reference XXX is listed as a using statement and is within a folder structure in the same project. It is not pointing to a separate project. I read the following Microsoft [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246) and everything in it appears to be correct. However the comment at the end suggests that error CS0246 can also be raise when the DLL was compiled for .Net 4.5, then copied to a Project with target Plattform 4.0.

Can someone please confirm if the above application pool setting will work with an application built for .Net v4.5 and suggest why the asmx file will not compile on the webserver please?

Comment: `.Net Framework v4.0.30319` is the base for .NET 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2 and 4.7 so yes, that's correct. The problem can also happen if there's an architecture mismatch (x86 vs x64)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem seems to be in the assembly which contains the XXX
>   type.You may have an older version or a different version of this assembly which does not contain this type or namespace.

- Find out the dll of your type
- Go to the bin directory and find out which version of this dll is present
- Cross check this version with the dev environment.
- If that does not work,you can manually copy this assembly from your dev environment and put in the IIS server

Answer (score 0):

Firstly thank you to those who took the time to reply.

The issue turned out to be that I needed to convert the virtual directory on IIS to an application. The option is on the right hand menu of the tree view of the virtual directories. It is not available if you chose 'view virtual directories' which is really helpful.